# How to add a 3rd party portal using JavaScript and HTML in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a Refill Prescription portal to a [WordPress website](https://clarkprofessionalpharmacy.com/refill-prescription/) and getting a no config id error and the portal will not load.

I created a file called **head** with the following JavaScript code

```js
attrLogo = 'color';
pid = 7343698782; // config1 pharmacy appcode
configid = '2000517c-b911-44b8-9ae6-0a845c692874'; // config2.0 Pharmacy uuid
```

and placed that file in a new folder named js in the root directory. Then, added

```html
<script src="https:clarkprofessionalpharmacy.com/js/head"></script>
```

to the header which can be seen [here](https://clarkprofessionalpharmacy.com/js/head).

Lastly, I added the HTML for **Refill**:

```html
<div class="refillApp"><div><script src="https://api-web.rxwiki.com/refill/shared_config/embedRefillApp.js"></script></div></div>
```

and HTML for **Sign in**:

```html
<div class="portalApp"><div><script src="https://api-web.rxwiki.com/portal/shared_config/embedPortalApp.js"></script></div></div>.
```

To eliminate a theme or reCaptcha problem, or a plugin conflict, I created a duplicate WP website with WP 2019 theme [here](https://budgetwebsiteco.com/cpp/refill-prescription/).

Comment: quick question....the head file....it looks like your config id is commented out.  could that be the issue?

Comment: You are right and the head file is fixed. It can be viewed in the browser and/or inspector. But, I don't see the code that was added to the header: 
`<script src="https://clarkprofessionalpharmacy.com/js/head'

Comment: In my test site https://budgetwebsiteco.com/cpp running WordPress 2019 and only 1 plugin (disable Gutenberg) I changed the js/head file to so it's not commented out but it's rendering it incorrectly defeating the purpose. Maybe a caching issue??? Thanks for your help!